# In jQuery: how to make a function update when the user expands the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell me how to use jQuery to make #mydiv stick to the full height of the window using jQuery when the user expnads the window. In this example, it only adjusts the height on page load. I need it to adjust whenever the user expands the window.

```
<html><head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>    

</head><body>
<style>

#mydiv {
background-color: blue;
height: 50px;
}

</style>

<div id="mydiv"></div>  
</body></html>

<script>

    if($("#mydiv").height() < $(window).height())
{
    $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
}  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you heard of Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#mydiv").height($(window).height()); // for onload

    //for resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks: I don't think I'm doing it right though: is this suppose to work?

<html><head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

</head><body><style>

#mydiv {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 50px;

}
</style>

<div id="mydiv"></div> 
</body></html>

<script>

$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
});

</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: that still needs to go inside of `$(function(){});` i edited the answer above.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you resizing that div? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have this solution (http://jsfiddle.net/4C89C/9/ ) to make divs equal length, but I need them to be at least be the size of the window when the content is really short. The example up above is a super simplified example so I could get the jQuery right. I'm going to test if they are less than the window. If so, then jQuery will stretch them down I hope.

Answer (score 2):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>  
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
          #mydiv {
            background-color: blue;
            height: 50px;
          }

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>


        <div id="mydiv"></div>  

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>   
        <script>
          $(window).on('load', function(){
            $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
            $(window).on('resize', function(){
              $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
            });
          });

        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly or not:

<html><head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

</head><body><style>

#mydiv {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 50px;

}
</style>

<div id="mydiv"></div> 
</body></html>

<script>

$(window).on('resize', function(){
 $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
});

</script>

</body>
</html>